# WHMCS service cancelled can not restore the invoice

Tags: website

I use the WHMCS system, I have a service for customer use.

The customer can cancel the service.

[image]

But there is a problem for me as administrator.

If customer canceled the service in error, I can transfer the service to him again, but the invoice will not calculate any more. It does not make the account active for that customer again.

> Cancellation Request Notice
>   A cancellation request exists for this item and so it will not be invoiced when due

(the cancellation request button for customer)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [official document](https://docs.whmcs.com/Products_Management#Voiding_Cancellation_Requests):

> If a Cancellation Request has been submitted by your client and they later change their mind, it is quick and easy to void their cancellation request. Simply navigate to Clients > Cancellation Requests, locate the cancellation you wish to remove, and then click the red X next to the request to remove it. This will stop the cancellation from processing automatically. You'll need to make sure to mark any invoices that were cancelled as "Unpaid" to prevent billing errors.

You just need to remove the cancellation request item.